# Linux-based RDBMS for Occasionally Connected Replication

Tags: linux, database-replication, occasionallyconnected

I am looking for a database replication solution which will meet the following requirements:

- Work with Linux-compatible RDBMS (Atom 32-bit single core architecture)
- Work in an occasionally connected environment, with two-way data flow
- Handle adding peers on the fly without a database engine restart

Here are the details of my configuration:  I am running multiple Linux based mini-servers at remote locations which often lose internet connection for up to a week at a time.  These mini-servers record data from users, and should replicate that data to any peers they can see on the network (more than one may be deployed in a given vlan for redundancy).  When connected to the internet, these mini-servers should synchronize with our central server, and data may flow from the mini-servers to the central server, or from the central server to the mini-servers.

I think SQL Server can handle most of this, but it doesn't run on Linux.  Any ideas?  I can do a fair amount of custom coding to get a solution working, but my current solution is my own custom replication system, which needless to say, doesn't hold up to enterprise software expectations...

Comment: I am not familiar with all its features, but I would believe that MySQL 5.5 fits your requirements (and it is free software, and probably runs on Linux and on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Unfortunately, MySQL requires a restart of the database engine every time you add a replication peer.  Because I need to be able to add peers on the fly, and my database needs to have high availability, this does not work for me.  Also, MySQL 5.1 (I am not sure of 5.5) has no knowledge of timezones, and since I have databases across timezones, this is critical for me.  I guess I should have mentioned that in the question...

Comment: Is the data big? And is the relational aspect important? Perhaps `unison` might be enough.... http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Comment: hmm, that's and interesting idea, but I think we have too much infrastructure invested in being able to query the data using sql from both ends... each individual replication usually only covers a few meg of data, but the overall structure size is nearing 100GB... very interesting approach though.

Comment: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~harmony/ could also be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take the lack of responses as an implicit 'no'.  If anyone is interested, I am planning my own postgres spin off with dynamic multi-peer replication support within the next year.